# Enterprise Services Alternative

Tags: .net, com+

Are there any alternatives to Serviced Components (COM+) in .NET?

I am looking for an on-demand (not always-running like Windows Service) manageable components to be hosted by the OS and be accessible locally (no requirement for remote connections).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it hosted out-of-process by the OS (i.e. with ability to change the runtime identity, etc), then COM+ is the closest fit. Other than that... connect to a service (such as WCF or POX) on a local IIS instance? Massively overkill etc... but in some ways, easier to deploy: once the IIS app exists, you can robocopy updates to the folder (which isn't an option with COM+).

I'd probably go COM+ here unless I *needed* that ability!

Comment: Thanks Marc. The problem with COM+ (and Serviced Components) is that although it has lots of features, it is difficult to deploy: Admin rights, GAC registration for ActivationOption.Server and all that. I'm looking for a framework that allows me to host my PONOs in a host running in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget about MSMQ triggering!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that just be a standard dll?

What do you mean by hosted?

*** EDIT ***
Oh, Out of process.  I'd use a WCF service in IIS over enterprise services (Serviced Components).

Comment: A dll is just code and would run in caller's process. I need something that is hosted by the OS. Like COM+

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want to have some supervision and control over process lifecycle activation and resource usage (CPU, memory, connections &c), but not necessarily things like automatically enforcing resource usage caps.

There's a good summary of options [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx). If you happen to have WS2008, Windows Process Activation Service is something I've been wishing for for quite a while now...